# How to determine if sql INSERTED or UPDATED?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Say I have a function like this:

```vb
Private Function addNicheMerge(ByVal tyNicheMergePOLE As typeNicheMergePOLE) As  Integer Implements IGenie.addNicheMerge
    Dim objParameterValues As New clsParameterValues
    Dim objCon As DbConnection
    Dim paramValues() As DbParameter
    Dim iConnectionBLL As DataAccessLayer.Connection.iConnectionBLL
    iConnectionBLL = New clsConnectionBLL()
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Try
        tyAcornCollision = New typeAcornCollision
        objParameterValues = New clsParameterValues
        objCon = iConnectionBLL.getDatabaseTypeByDescription("GENIE2")
        Using objCon
            Dim strSQL As String
            strSQL = "If NOT Exists (SELECT * FROM dbNicheMergeLog WHERE MasterID=@MasterID AND ChildID = @ChildID) "
            strSQL = strSQL & "INSERT INTO dbNicheMergeLog (MasterID, ChildID, DateAdded, GenieUpdated, done, CheckedByUser, MergeTypeID, Usercode, LastUpdated) VALUES (@MasterID, @ChildID, getDate(), 0, 0, @CheckedByUser, @MergeTypeID, '', " & _ "GetDate()) Else Update dbNicheMergeLog SET LastUpdated = getdate() WHERE MasterID=@MasterID AND ChildID = @ChildID"
            objParameterValues.AssignParameterValues("@MasterID", tyNicheMergePOLE.MasterID, 1)

            objParameterValues.AssignParameterValues("@ChildID", tyNicheMergePOLE.ChildID, 1)
            objParameterValues.AssignParameterValues("@MergeTypeID", tyNicheMergePOLE.MergeTypeID, 1)
            objParameterValues.AssignParameterValues("@CheckedByUser", 0, 1)
            paramValues = objParameterValues.getParameterValues
            intCount = clsDatabaseHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(objCon, CommandType.Text, strSQL, paramValues)

            Return intCount
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return -2
    Finally
        ' If objCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        '    objCon.Close()
        ' End If
        objCon = Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Is there a way to determine whether an  insertion or update  took place?

Comment: As far as I can see from you code - you do not deleting anything. Just inserting or updating.

Comment: @Andy Korneyev, I have modified the question.

Comment: Who has formatted the sql so that it won't compile anymore?

Comment: I've never tried it, but maybe the same query can select the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` after performing the conditional insert?  If there's an identity, something was inserted.  If there isn't, nothing was.  Not sure if it'll work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @David: i thought the same, that should work. On update you get `NULL`.

Comment: Are you on SQL Server? If so, the *action* keyword of the OUTPUT clause for a MERGE operation performs exactly what you desire. The OUTPUT clause is also the correct way to retrieve the surrogate key value for the record *upserted*.

Comment: I suspect that the *need* to determine if an insert or an update was performed is a sign that this "silent upsert" pattern shouldn't be used in the first place.  The point of this "upsert" query is *specifically* to hide this information.  So if the information is needed, then it sounds like this isn't the right approach.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: but [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) says that _"$action
Is available only for the MERGE statement. "_

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Of course - because that is the only statement for which the operation type is not implicit in the statement performed. However a MERGE is exactly what OP requires to properly peroform the described action.

Comment: @David: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is for *low concurrency environments* only; otherwise use an OUTPUT clause on your INSERT or MERGE statement.  Check the postings at the bottom of this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Good point.  Though it's not clear what link you're referring to.  Maybe the MSDN article Tim posted?

Comment: If all you want to know if records got inserted or deleted, ALL you need to do is check `intCount > 0` . just remember, your insert may invoke a trigger which may also insert or delete something, your `intCount` will reflect that. This is why don't do `If intCount = 1` on insert.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sql server, you could use an output clause to determine if an update happened

```
 Update dbNicheMergeLog SET LastUpdated = 
                    getdate() WHERE MasterID=@MasterID AND 
                   ChildID = @ChildID
                   OUTPUT count(*)
```

Then in vb use

```
dim updateCount as int =  Convert.ToInt32(clsDatabaseHelper.ExecuteScalar())
```

Comment: I didn't spot that, assuming that only one row is inserted/updated, then output 0 on the insert might work to communicate what has happened, then interpret that in vb

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Output deleted.*
```

in your update query to get the results that were lost on update, something like this:

```
Create Table #abctest(
Id int identity,Name varchar(200))

Insert into #abctest(Name)
Values('abcd'),('bcde'),('cdef'),('defg'),('efgh'),('fghi')

Update #abctest Set Name='xyz' OUTPUT Deleted.* Where Id=2
```

The above query will give you an output

```
Id  Name
2   bcde
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL:

```
WITH new (
     MasterID
    ,ChildID
    ,DateAdded
    ,GenieUpdated
    ,done
    ,CheckedByUser
    ,MergeTypeID
    ,Usercode
    ,LastUpdated
)
 AS(
  SELECT
     @MasterID
    ,@ChildID
    ,getDate()
    ,0
    ,0
    ,@CheckedByUser
    ,@MergeTypeID
    ,''
    ,getdate()
)
MERGE INTO dbNicheMergeLog t
USING new
   ON t.MasterID = new.MasterID
  AND t.ChildID  = new.ChildID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (
     MasterID
    ,ChildID
    ,DateAdded
    ,GenieUpdated
    ,done
    ,CheckedByUser
    ,MergeTypeID
    ,Usercode
    ,LastUpdated
) 
VALUES (
     new.MasterID
    ,new.ChildID
    ,new.DateAdded
    ,new.GenieUpdated
    ,new.done
    ,new.CheckedByUser
    ,new.MergeTypeID
    ,new.Usercode
    ,new.LastUpdated
)
OUTPUT $action as Action
;
```